# Powershell CSOM to list out all Site groups and users of that group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am able to fetch all the site groups however all this groups are not showing in site. It is showing extra groups when i run the csom power shell and how do i filter only the groups which are showing on site UI.

here is my Sample code

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"   
Add-Type -Path "C:\\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"     

#SPO Client Object Model Context 
$spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteUrl) 
$spoCredentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($sUserName, $sPassword)   
$spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials       

$web = $spoCtx.Web
$spGroups =$web.SiteGroups
$spoCtx.Load($spGroups)
$spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

foreach($group in $spGroups)
{
    Write-Host " Group Name = $($group.Title)"
    Write-Host " Group is hidden = $($group.IsHiddenInUI)"
    Write-Host " Group User Count = $($group.Users.Count)"
}
```

I have 2 question

1. How do i filter groups which can show only the groups which are
   showing in Site
2. $group.IsHiddenInUI, $group.Users.Count is giving not intialized exception exception

Comment: Are you running these commands on server itself or from a remote machine?

Comment: Hi,
I am running this script from remote machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the following in your code to avoid not initialized exceptions:

```
$web = $spoCtx.Web
$spGroups =$web.SiteGroups
$spoCtx.Load($spGroups)
$spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

foreach($group in $spGroups)
{
    $spoCtx.Load($group)
    $users = $group.Users
    $spoCtx.Load($users)
    $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery()


    Write-Host " Group Name = $($group.Title)"
    Write-Host " Group is hidden = $($group.IsHiddenInUI)"
    Write-Host " Group User Count = $($users.Count)"
}
```

In short since you are using CSOM, you need to load each collection to get it's properties to work otherwise it will throw NOT INITIALIZED EXCEPTION.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. I am able to get User count but not able to retrieve the `$group.IsHiddenInUI` giving the NOT INITIALIZED EXCEPTION

Comment: Can you please tell me how do retrieve Permission levels tagged for the Groups like "Full Control", "Contribute"

Comment: Permissions are not tied to groups, they are based on list or library. For example, a group can have View-only access to one list while Full control on another list.

Comment: However Google for RoleAssignments and RoleDefinitions to get the permissions

Comment: Thank you..! I have got through RoleAssignments and RoleDefinitions